# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't get access to my recently created database. I have tried repeatedly to flush privileges but am unable to reset the password to gain access.

I get the following error when trying to access it on the command line after typing `mysql -u rails_user -p` then entering what I believe should be the correct password:

> ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'rails_user'@'localhost'
>   (using password: YES)

Here's my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: rails_user
  password: examplepassword
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development
```

Also, when I enter: `grant all on simple_cms_development.* to 'rails_user'@'localhost' identified by 'examplepassword';` on the command line I get the following error:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'identified by 'examplepassword'' at line 1

I've read other examples somewhat similar to my own here on stackoverflow but the solutions do not work to successfully configure and connect my database to my rails app. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you forget your password for mysql or getting access denied while doing `mysql -u UserName -p` 
then you can open mysql by skipping authorization and then change the password.
See [Here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password/)

Comment: When I type: update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("newpassword") where User='rails_user'; as  shown in the link I still get the following error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("newpassword") where User='rails_user'' at line 1
mysql> flush privileges;

Comment: I get this error when trying to change the password for some reason. "mysql> update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("newpasso") where User='rails_user';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '("newpassword") where User='rails_user'' at line 1"